# Can a DBMS support several DSL languages?

Tags: sql, database

My question is about DBMS. As you know A data Sub-language is a computer language used to define or manipulate the structure of a relational database management system(DBMS) e.g QBE, SQL. It's difference between Domain specific_language and data Sub-language.

Can a DBMS support several DSL(Data Sub-Language)?

Comment: Ali, could you please specify what DBMS and what DSL languages are we talking about?

Comment: yeah, sure! but what Database Management System and what DSL? By the way, I thought you mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language by DSL. So you should ask something like: Does the *Oracle* DBMS support the *Regular Expressions*? You have to be specific because this question is too general.

Comment: Dear bpgerpo, A data Sub-language is a computer language used to define or manipulate the structure of a relational database management system(DBMS) e.g QBE, SQL.It's difference between Domain specific_language and data Sub-language.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, some *database management systems* do support several *domain-specific languages*. *SQL Server*, for example, supports both *Transact-SQL* and *XQuery*. *SQL Server Analysis Services* supports *MDX* as well.

Update:

Since you have clarified that *[DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSL_%28disambiguation%29)* means Edgar Codd's *data sublanguage* this changes things. *XQuery* and *MDX* are query-only languages so they don't qualify as complete [data sublanguages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublanguage#In_Relational_Database_Theory) by Codd's definition.